# Excel VBA connect to Access Northwind.mdb from Excel and run the Product List query

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am learning VBA to integrate an Excel macro that will connect to the Northwind.mdb database in Access 2003 and then run its query eg. Current Product List. Is this possible? If so how?

Thanks for any help

Pete

Comment: Have you looked into the `Excel Menu` --> `Data` --> `Get External Data` --> `From Access`?

Comment: I don't want to get I need to run the query in access? The excel macro should call it?

Comment: I see. In this case the question is a duplicate of the following and should be closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437642/running-an-access-query-from-excel